# React-pixi and Reagent cause an Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, pixi.js, reagent

I'm trying to build a game in Clojurescript using Reagent and React-Pixi, but as soon as I try to do anything I get:

> Error: Invariant Violation: PIXIStage.render() A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

A minimal case to reproduce this is:

```
(ns react-sprites.core
  (:require [cljsjs.react-pixi]
            [reagent.core :as r]))

(def stage (r/adapt-react-class js/ReactPIXI.Stage))
(defn root [] [stage {:width 300 :height 300}])

(r/render-component [root]
                    (. js/document (getElementById "app")))
```

specifically, using the `react-pixi` and `reagent` versions:

```
[reagent "0.6.0-rc"]
[cljsjs/react-pixi "0.8.1-0"]
```

### Additional Information

I've gone and traced around in the debugger, and the invariant violation is being thrown on a `canvas` that's being generated by `React.createElement("canvas")` in [ReactPIXI's `render()` method](https://github.com/Izzimach/react-pixi/blob/master/src/ReactPIXI.js#L407), so apparently the canvas being created isn't a valid `ReactComponent`. I really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: GAH! It started spontaneously working, I'm going to have to try to break it again so I can figure out what changed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem here came down to a version incompatibility. I thought I was running on Reagent 0.6 and using the latest React, but it seems like the app didn't get properly updated and was still using 0.5.1 which uses a React version that's incompatible with react-pixi's. To fix it, I had to force the update, at which point it started working. While reproducing this issue I also had problems with the browser cache.

In summary, things worth trying include:

```
$ lein clean
# edit the dependency information
$ lein figwheel
```

- Clearing cache
- Downgrading then upgrading versions (perhaps?)

As a side note, I was led astray by a combination of other error messages I found while debugging, some of which warn about the possibility that there were multiple React versions running on the page. Since I didn't get one of those, I had prematurely ruled out the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [puck](https://github.com/lambdaisland/puck), which is a ClojureScript wrapper around PixiJS. This may be another route to apply ClojureScript in building game.